# GestureDetector ontap() gets triggered by build

Tags: flutter

In my `build`, I have this function that basically stacks a `button` and a `counter`, i'm also passing a function (this let's me reuse the `buildbuttoncolumn` for all buttons instead of copying code arround

my build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<Widget> _layouts = [
  _videoInfo(),
  _channelInfo(),
  _comment(),
  _moreInfo(),
  VideoList(
    channel: widget.channel,
    isMiniList: true,
    currentVideoId: widget.detail.id
  ),
];

if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
  _layouts.clear();
}

return Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      _buildVideoPlayer(context),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: _layouts,
        ),
      )
    ]));
```

}

my videoinfo:

```
Widget _videoInfo() {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.detail.title),
      subtitle: Text(widget.detail.viewCount + ' . ' + widget.detail.publishedTime),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildButtomColumn(Icons.thumb_up, widget.detail.likeCount, function: _like(widget.detail.id, true)),
          _buildButtomColumn(Icons.thumb_down, widget.detail.dislikeCount, function: _like(widget.detail.id, false)),
          _buildButtomColumn(CupertinoIcons.share_up, "Partilhar"), //function: share(context, widget.detail.player)
          _buildButtomColumn(Icons.add_to_photos, "Guardar"),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

}

```
 _buildButtomColumn(Icons.thumb_up, widget.detail.likeCount, function: _like(widget.detail.id, true)),
```

the method then does something like this:

```
Widget _buildButtomColumn(IconData icon, String text, {function}) {
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => function 
    child: Column(.....
```

oh and here's the like:

```
_like(String videoId, bool liked) {
  youtubeAPI.likeDislikeVideo(videoId, liked);
}
```

when I open the page, the `onTap` gets triggered without me actually pressing the button.

Comment: Where is `_buildButtomColumn` first used?

Comment: @pskink, thanks man but if you need it to "compile" you prob don't know the answer

Comment: @dev-aentgs edited on the main thread

Comment: @pskink posting actual code does not help either. it's a type of problem that you either know or not. has nothing to do with compilation.

Comment: @pskink and heck the only thing I didnt post was whats in the column, wich can be nothing, as the problem is not there. just close the column and method and it will compile...

Comment: @pskink  again... I POSTED ALL OF THE GESTUREDETECTOR CODE the only "pseudo" is a column. with nothing inside. and no. the gesture is not the root. the build is.

Comment: Without registering a `Tap` gesture the `onTap` callback cannot be triggered. How do you determine that `onTap` was triggered ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs well because the share function runs

Comment: ok, can you once check if there are any other places in code from where `share function` is called? .Just to confirm that this is the cause can you make `onTap: () => function ` to `onTap: () { print(' Triggered from onTap'); return function ;}`  so we can see in the console.

Comment: I did, that's the only place. also.. all of the funcions get called as well, not just the share (the two _likes)

Comment: oh ok.  can you make `onTap: () => function`  to `onTap: () { print(' Triggered from onTap'); return function ;} ` .

Comment: doesn't print. could it be that you can't pass a function as an argument? O.O

Comment: we can pass function as an argument. There is probably some other place in the code from where it is getting called.

Comment: i did a ctrl+f and that's the only place

Comment: This is a bit confusing but i think while building the `_buildButtomColumn`, the functions are getting triggered.

Comment: yep. if i don't do it like this, it doesn't get called. oh well. can't really save that repeated code then. thanks

Comment: There is something we have missed out in passing the function properly, cannot get it right just yet but will revisit if i find the proper way.

Answer (score 4):

**Where is the problem?**

You are calling that function yourself, there is no problem with `onTap` callback and it is not fired somehow without user interaction

Next snippet performs `_like` function invocation and pass returned result to `function:...` arg ([refer to lang tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions-as-first-class-objects))

```
function: _like(widget.detail.id, true)
```

You can prevent such situations if you declare `function:` argument type as `Function` and you will get static analysis type error before you run code

```
_buildButtomColumn(IconData icon, String text, {Function function})
```

**Back to you code - how to fix it?**

1. pass function argument directly to onTap argument

```
Widget _buildButtomColumn(IconData icon, String text, {VoidCallback function}) {
/// here I enforced type as VoidCallback - it is typedef for `void Function()`
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: function, // <-- pass function, onTap type is VoidCallback
    child: Column(.....
```

2.a. pass anonymous function with desired payload

```
_buildButtomColumn(Icons.thumb_up, widget.detail.likeCount,
   function: () => youtubeAPI.likeDislikeVideo(videoId, liked), // <-- this will be invoked later 
)
```

2.b. this variant is for sake of completeness

declare [callable class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes) and pass it's instance to `function:...` arg ()

```
class LikeCommand {
  final String videoId;
  final bool liked;
  LikeCommand(this.videoId, this.liked);
  void call() => youtubeAPI.likeDislikeVideo(videoId, liked);
}

_buildButtomColumn(Icons.thumb_up, widget.detail.likeCount,
   function: LikeCommand(videoId, liked),
)
```

PS I recommend declaring types, since dart is a strongly typed language and specifying types will save you from typical problems in the future

PPS feel free to reach me in comments

Comment: Thanks, refactoring the original code according to your answer should solve.

Comment: this does not resolve the problem have you found any other solution?

Comment: @RohitSharma ask question with your problem, this answer explains concrete problem